# Pass component x or y from parent component to child component and display it

Tags: angular

I would like to do something funky in Angular.

I would like to pass two types of components (x and y) from my parent to my child component and display it there. Depending on the state I would either pass component x or component y down.

The practical reason for this is that I have a table-data component and a table-loading component. I would like to display display the loading component when my data is being retrieved and the display the table-data component when all the data is present.

But I want my child component not to worry about which component to display.

Currently I work with this boolean `loading` flag to determine what component to show like this:

```html
<ui-game-table *ngIf="!loading"
               [games$]="games$">
</ui-game-table>
<app-game-table-loader *ngIf="loading"
                       [games]="loadingGames">
</app-game-table-loader>
```

But what I would like to have is to pass the component that needs to be displayed down like e.g. this

```js
@Input()
public gameTable: GameTableLoaderComponent | GameTableComponent;
```

And display it something like:

```html
<gameTable></gameTable>
```

Does anyone know if something like this is possible?

Comment: what is the problem in using ngif using loading variable

Comment: @KautilyaKatiha I would like to write view components where there is no logic in the component itself. I agree that it is not a big issue to do this very straight forward kind of logic, but I am just curious if it is possible.

Comment: @user1352048 Can you have a look at the answer I have posted. Does that help?

Comment: @Saksham My bad I missed this comment! Will have a look at it thanks :)!

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible by using chained `ComponentFactoryResolver` which is used to dynamically create a reference to a component and inject it in the component template.

The example [HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-component-loading-using-factory-resolver) based on click of buttons from a component dynamically loads the respective component in a `template` element.